# Global PWA for a NX-Workspace

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, nrwl-nx, nrwl, nx-workspace

I am using nx workspace in my angular projects. In my nx workspace there are multiple projects I have added. When I am trying to install PWA for that It is installing to each project .But I want a global PWA for complete workspace. Whatever projects are there inside the Workspace it will come under one PWA , basically one Root level PWA a for all the projects not individual projects ?

I have tried with Individual Projects level PWA but I need a root/global label PWA.

In a single domain all those are deployed (i.e --- Let suppose domain is [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and projects are suppose A , B , C inside a nx workspace . To access Project A we need hit [www.example.com/A](http://www.example.com/A) similarly for B we need to hit [www.example.com/B](http://www.example.com/B) same for C also.

So now I have added the service worker in A project , B project ...etc . But to run PWA for entire example.com it is not possible. So we have to install example.com/A , example.com/B separately . But I am searching for a solution to enable PWA for entire example.com workspace not individual project.